# How can I have a function pointer template as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I am trying to create a class template that expects a type and a function pointer as template parameters. The function pointer is expected to be a member function of the type passed in. I want the user of the class template to be able to pass in a void member function of the type passed in. That member function will then be called on instances of the type passed in every time a certain function of the class template is called. It's a bit hard to explain but it's supposed to work sort of like this:

```
template<Type, Function> // For the purpose of explaining it
class Foo
{
public:
    template<Args... args>
    void callOnAll(Args... args)
    {
        for(Type* ptr : ptrs_)
        {
            ptr->Function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Type*> ptrs_;
}
```

Assuming that something like this is possible (which I realize it might not be), the key would have to be getting the template parameters for the class right, and getting the `update` function right. This is what I've come up with but I still can't get it to work:

```
template<typename T, template<typename... Args> void(T::*func)(Args... args)>
class EngineSystem
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void update(Args... args)
    {
        for (T* handler : handlers_)
        {
            ((*handler).*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<T*> handlers_;
};
```

The code above does not compile. It points me to the line where I declare the template parameters for the class, underlines `void` and says `expected 'class' or 'typename'`.

Is it clear what I'm trying to achieve, and is it possible?

Comment: You need to store the actual function pointer somewhere as well, you are currently not doing that

Comment: @UnholySheep I see. Not too familiar with function pointers so that's why. But the code I presented will not compile either way. It's giving me different errors. Check the edit I added in the question body under the example code

Comment: @UnholySheep storing a function pointer as a non-type template parameter is fine.  The issue here is just that you can't have non-type template template parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ doesn't allow non-type template template parameters.  That means you can't have a parameter-pack for your member-function pointer parameter.

Assuming you're using C++17 or newer, you can use an `auto` template parameter instead:

```
template<typename T, auto func>
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void update(Args... args)
    {
        for (T* handler : handlers_)
        {
            (handler->*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<T*> handlers_;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ac61c8967fee482)

Technically that will accept any object for `func`, but assuming `update` is called, then `(handler->*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` still has to be well-formed or compilation will fail.

If you want compilation to fail even if `update` never gets called, you could use some type traits and a `static_assert` (or some SFINAE hackery, if you need it) to ensure that `func` is actually a pointer to a member function of `T`:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct IsPointerToMemberOf : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct IsPointerToMemberOf<T, U T::*> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct IsPointerToMemberFunctionOf 
    : std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        IsPointerToMemberOf<T, U>::value && std::is_member_function_pointer<U>::value
    >
{};

template<typename T, auto func>
class EngineSystem
{
    static_assert(IsPointerToMemberFunctionOf<T, decltype(func)>::value, "func must be a pointer to a member function of T");
    //...
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6df9ca43d7331cce)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
class EngineSystem
{
    public:
    EngineSystem(void(T::*fun)(Args... args)): fun(fun)
    {
    }
    void update(Args... args)
    {
        for (T* handler : handlers_)
        {
            (handler->*fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    }
    void push(T* t){
        handlers_.push_back(t);
    }
private:
    void(T::*fun)(Args... args);
    std::vector<T*> handlers_;
};
struct A {
    int x = 3;
    void fn(int a, int b){
        std::cout << a << b << x;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto makeEngine(void(T::*fun)(Args... args)){
    return EngineSystem<T, Args...>(fun);
}

int main() {
    EngineSystem<A, int, int> as(&A::fn);

    // or deduce types automatically
    auto es = makeEngine(&A::fn);
    A a;
    es.push(&a);
    es.update(1,2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Pcdf9K9nz

Comment: A type could be a structure with a member function. That member function could even be variadic. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q83vMxxhz